# Text too close to the edge in html email

Tags: html, css, email

I am creating an html email and my menu keeps going to close to the side on Microsoft outlook 2010. It works fine in gmail, and on Outlook live but not here.

See image below. One on the left is outlook and one on the right is every other email provider.

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxQWc.png)

I am quite new to coding but I am not sure why it works everywhere else but not here

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see what you have already please?

Comment: Have you tried adding a padding?

Comment: padding-right:15px;" Whole code:

<td align="right" valign="middle" style="font-size:11px;color:#999999;width:300px;">
                            <div class="contentEditableContainer contentTextEditable" style="min-height:0px;padding-right:15px;">
                              <div class="contentEditable">
                                <p style="color:#ffffff;">
                                  <a target="_blank" href="#" style="text-decoration:none;color:#ffffff;font-weight:bold;">All News</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add margin-right in p tag

```
<p style='margin-right:30px'>your code</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add padding to where you want to add the spacing

Answer (score 0):

Just Add padding-right:10px; (Insert the space as you want).
Try adding padding-right to the table tag